# How can I use XPATH to add data of subtree to main tree  in Python/Django

Tags: python, xml, django, dom, xpath

I'm using etree to parse an external xml file and trying to get the `listing data` from a  tree from the below external xml file and add the subtree `agancy` data to it. I am able to pull the data for `isting` and `agancy` just fine seperately, but don't know how to merge them so that the `listing` gets the correct `agency` info.

xml:

```
<response>
    <listing>
        <bathrooms>2.1</bathrooms>
        <bedrooms>3</bedrooms>
        <agency>
            <name>Bob's Realty</name>
            <phone>555-693-4356</phone>
        </agency>
    </listing>
    <listing>
        <bathrooms>3.1</bathrooms>
        <bedrooms>5</bedrooms>
        <agency>
            <name>Larry's Homes</name>
            <phone>555-324-6532</phone>
        </agency>
    </listing>
</response>
```

python:

```
tree = lxml.etree.parse("http://www.someurl.com?random=blahblahblah")
listings = tree.xpath("/response/listing")
agencies = tree.xpath("/response/listing/agency")

listings_info = []

for listing in listings:
    this_value = {
        "bedrooms":listing.findtext("bedrooms"),
        "bathrooms":listing.findtext("bathrooms"),
        }

        for agency in agencies:
            this_value['agency']= agency.findtext("name")


    listings_info.append(this_value)
```

I tried adding this at one point just above where the `listing_info.append(this_value)` occurs, however this is not correct and just appends the last agency value to every listing.

I'm outputting the data into json and here's what it looks like (You can see how one agency's info is being put into both results:

```
    {"listings":[{"agency": "Bob's Realty", "phone":"555-693-4356" "bathrooms": "2.1", "bedrooms": "3"},{"agency": "Bob's Realty", "phone":"555-693-4356" "bathrooms": "3.1", "bedrooms": "5"} ]}
```

How can I merge the data from `response/listing/agency` with `response/listing` in my original `for` statement?

Comment: What is the questions? Can you provide example of (incorrect) output and correct (desired) output?

Comment: Yes you're right sorry. I updated the question to be more clear and added the json output that I am getting.

Comment: So, what is the final XML document you want as result? Please, provide this in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `listing.xpath('agency/name/text()')[0]` as you iterate through your list to get the agency's name for just that listing.

```
for listing in listings:
    this_value = {
        'bedrooms': listing.findtext('bedrooms'),
        'bathrooms': listing.findtext('bathrooms'),
        'agency': listing.xpath('agency/name/text()')[0]
    }
    listings_info.append(this_value)
```

Comment: by any chance can you tell me what the `[0]` stands for? Your original solution works, however, I've added a bit to my xml that I'm trying to pull from, but get the error `list index out of range`.

Comment: `xpath` should return a list with only one item, the name of the agency. If it's out of range perhaps your actual XML is different than your example and you'll want to account for that.